# Basic Supabase edge function throws error

Tags: serverless, supabase

I am currently trying my hand with Supabase's edge functions. I don't know anything about this area, so I tried the quickstart tutorial first. I created the simple "hello-world" function (from the documentation https://supabase.com/docs/guides/functions/quickstart) and tried to call it from my java script code. I have turned off the JWT verification. But when I call the function I always get "FunctionsFetchError" back. In the dashboard the error looks like this:

```
Log Event Message
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at parse ()
at packageData (ext:deno_fetch/22_body.js:362:14)
at consumeBody (ext:deno_fetch/22_body.js:239:12)
at async Server. (file:///src/index.ts:7:23)
at async Server.#respond (https://deno.land/std@0.168.0/http/server.ts:221:24)
```

If you want to try it yourself: https://gwhzelyucjyglpyptrox.functions.supabase.co/hello-world

I didn't change anything at all in the code of the example function, but still can't get it to work.

Comment: Can you share the source of the function deployed?

The question should be self-contained.

Comment: I updated my post, but I don't understand what you mean with "self-contained".

Comment: @WinterTribute: "Self-contained" means that a reader does not have to follow a link to understand the whole of the question. It is preferable because links can change over time, to the degree that the question may not make sense in the future if the content changes (e.g. it is deleted).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Finally I figured out that is because the request has been consumed during the OPTION check request.

To avoid this error:

```
   serve(async (req) => {

  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    return new Response('ok', { headers: { ...corsHeaders }, status: 200 })
  } 
  // send a response to the OPTION request before you use the req object.


  const origin = req.headers.get('Origin')
  console.log('origin is :', origin)
  const { test } = await req.json()
  // Now you can consume the req object and do your things.
```

Comment: I had pretty much the same problem, but with a twist: I didn't change the request method from GET to POST in Thunder Client.